# Getting Photo ID (URL Parameter) with preg_match_all (PHP Regex)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm searching through text with [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). I'm searching for "photo.php?ID=", because **I would like to pull that ID parameter out (ID can be alphanumerical)**.

Example text:

```
"Here is an article with an <img src="/photo.PHP?ID=pic_14" /> image."
"Or here is an article with a different <img src="http://www.example.com/photo.PHP?ID=14" /> image."
```

I've tried some pretty awful regex I would say:

```
preg_match_all("/photo\/(.*?)\"/", $text, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It assumes your ID is alpha-numerical.

```
preg_match_all("/photo.PHP\?ID=(\w+)/i", $text, $matches);
```

Comment: Updated question to state that ID is alphanumerical. Can you please update your regex?

Comment: That's not finding anything, using my example text from the question

Comment: I missed the .php in my response, I have updated it accordingly. I also added a flag to make the regex case insensitive so it will match '.PHP' or '.php'. Note that will make ID case insensitive as well, so the 'i' at the end of the regex can be removed if you do not need it to be case insensitive.